# what is the Difference between spring.profiles.active=production vs spring.profiles.active=local

Tags: spring

When I try to run an spring boot application.

There is a property available in`application.properties` file where it has the property `spring.profiles.active=production`.

While  search the details about this property in web I got to know that `spring.profiles.active=local`.

Can anyone kindly explain these details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain environment-specific choices made for development aren’t appropriate or won’t work when the application transitions from development to production.

Consider database configuration, for instance. In a development environment,
you’re likely to use an embedded database preloaded with test data like this:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
    .addScript("classpath:schema.sql")
    .addScript("classpath:test-data.sql")
    .build();
}
```

In a production setting,
you may want to retrieve a `DataSource` from your container using JNDI:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName("jdbc/myDS");
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setResourceRef(true);
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setProxyInterface(javax.sql.DataSource.class);
    return (DataSource) jndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

Starting with Spring 3.1 you can use profiles. Method-leve `@Profile` annotation works starting from Spring 3.2. In Spring 3.1 it's only class-level.

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
    @Profile("development")
    public DataSource embeddedDataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
        .addScript("classpath:schema.sql")
        .addScript("classpath:test-data.sql")
        .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("production")
    public DataSource jndiDataSource() {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName("jdbc/myDS");
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setResourceRef(true);
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setProxyInterface(javax.sql.DataSource.class);
        return (DataSource) jndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject();
    }
}
```

Each of the `DataSource` beans is in a profile and will only be created if the prescribed profile is active. Any bean that isn’t given a profile will always be created, regardless of what profile is active.

You can give any logical names to your profiles.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this property to let Spring know which profiles should be active ( to be used while starting application). For example, if you give it in application.properties or via argument -Dspring.profiles.active=prod; you tell Spring, to run under prod profile. Which means -  Spring will look for "application-prod.yml" or "application-prod.properties"file and will load all properties under it.

You can also annotate bean (method or class) by @Profile("PROFILE_NAME") - this ensures, the bean is mapped to certain profile.

You can pass multiple profiles to spring.profiles.active.

More information in docs - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: Your answer will become more clear if you use the syntax highlighting and text formatting in your answer. Also couldn't hurt to check your spelling... unless you really want to `annotate bean` (method or class). You could also mention that runtime environments and the difference between dev/local vs production?